# How to use Swann's Immortality Protocol?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft II, when using Swann in Co-op, how do you activate/use the Immortality Protocol? I have earned it, but I'm unsure what I have to do to get it to work and I can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Before the unit (Thor/Siege tank) is destroyed, the option will not be available, however it will alert you that it will be an option:
[image: Immortality Protocol Enabled]
Once the unit is destroyed there will be a Repair button that can be selected to activate the repairs:[image: Select Repair to start repairing]
I think we may have been playing a mutation Coop game and it wasn't available because my unit was burning at the time. I looked everywhere but I wasn't able to find a repair button. The next time I played I the repair button was very apparent.

Answer (score 2):

To use [Immortality Protocol](http://liquipedia.net/starcraft2/Immortality_Protocol), the unit needs to be destroyed.

When the Thor unit is destroyed, if you have the Immortality Protocol, you will have a 400 HP Unit that you can select, and rebuild the Thor.

Note:  Google Search for "Immortality Protocol" will tell you everything you need to know on the first hit.  The question is extremely poorly researched, and it seems like no attempt was made.

Comment: Actually, I did do fair amount of research, all the information I found talked about how the IP works in campaign but not in the Co-op. It seems to work differently between the campaign and the Co-op. I was looking for more for an answer like: research X, then when the unit is destroyed, select the wreckage and click Y. Perhaps I missed the button to click while playing, but I couldn't find the way to use IP on the battlefield.